# Upgrade Huawei Ascend Y530 to Lollipop or Kitkat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, 5.0-lollipop

How do i upgrade my Huawei Ascend Y530 phone to KitKat or Lollipop?
Please, no surveys.
Also, it is the MEO version (100 euros), not the Original (120 euros).
It is rooted and currently running Android 4.3

Comment: Anyone? I can't seem to find any ROM's.

Comment: *Anyone? I can't seem to find any ROM's.* -- [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device). Have you looked  this answer?

Comment: Not finding any ROM.